# Set divs to fade in when a href is clicked (jQuery maybe?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

So here is a project I'm working on for a friend - http://projects.beauaugust.co.uk/cheatulous/

What I need to happen is when one of the links in .menu are clicked, the divs inside .items fade in. I already have it so that the .sort div resizes to hold the content, I just need those divs to fade in afterward so it looks like the content is inside it, if that makes sense. If you click on one of the links inside the menu bar in the demo you'll see.

Cheers as ever, If I haven't given enough information I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").hide();
    $(".menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //stops page from reloading on link click
        $(".item").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Something like that?

**Alternative:**

If you want the divs to fade in after the page has loaded (i.e. you want to actually switch to another html page and THEN have the divs fade in) the above won't work. Instead you could simply add:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Which will make the .item divs flash (hide and then fade in, which is what you want afaik) on page reloads.

**Alternative 2:**

If you want the five divs currently displaying to be hidden when you first enter the page, and then be displayed as you click ANY link (i.e. they will be popped into view as the yellow background slides down), you could use `display:none` on .item in the CSS, and then use fade in on the links as above.

Comment: `$('.menu href')`? I don't think that's valid.

Comment: That looks promising, but I'm unsure how the premise works. Do I need to set the .items div to visibility: hidden for this to work? And can I set a delay on it?

Comment: If you want the .item divs to be hidden before you can use $(".item").hide(); first. For the delay. use fadeIn("slow"). http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if you checked out my link, but what I need is a little hard to explain. I basically would like it so that the .items div is hidden, and fades in when an item in the menu is clicked.

Comment: Do you have one div per link, or do you have a number of divs under every link? As it is right now I can only see five divs that will always be there. I'm not sure I fully understand the context :) Check alternative 2.

Comment: AH! That would be what I'd need. I'll give that a go now. Yeah I should have explained better. I'd like those 5 divs to be hidden upon the page loading, and then they appear when a menu button is clicked. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I want to make sure I actually understood as well. And +answer if it did work. ;-)

Comment: Ok hang on I'll show you what I have in a JSFiddle, it didn't work. I think I'm doing something wrong my end :T

Comment: NO WAIT SOLVED! Haha. My fault. I typed in the div name wrong. Feel free to check it out update now, http://projects.beauaugust.co.uk/cheatulous/

What I did in the end was just add your line 
$(".item").hide().fadeIn("slow");
into another function I had! Thanks :)